# Optimize Large MySQL ResultSet

Tags: java, javafx

I am running a query against a database, and it works fine, but building the data to place into a table takes a while. I am retrieving 500,000 rows of data, and I don't think that it should take very long to display that, but my Application stops responding because of how long it takes. I have tried the same query in different applications and they load the really fast. Is there anything I can do to speed mine up?

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList>> runQueries(String query){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(query);
        while(true){
            HashMap<String, ArrayList> hm = new HashMap<>();
            // Get next resultset if no resultset was returned.
            // The query was either an insert, update or delete
            if(stmt.getUpdateCount() > -1){
                stmt.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }
            // If the resultset is null exit
            if(stmt.getResultSet() == null){
                break;
            }
            // We have a resultset!
            // Save the columns to an array
            // We can then display them later
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList();
            for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++){
                columns.add(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            }
            // Save the columns to the hashmap
            hm.put("columns", columns);

            // We now need to save the rows to an array as well
            // We can then display them later as well
            ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            while(rs.next()){
                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for(int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++){
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                oblist.add(row);
            }
            ArrayList<ObservableList> rows = new ArrayList<>();
            rows.add(oblist);
            rs.close();
            // Save the rows to the hashmap
            hm.put("rows", rows);
            // Save the hashmap to the final array
            arrayList.add(hm);
            stmt.getMoreResults();
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Mysql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

**Edit:**

I have narrowed it down to the section that takes a while to run:

```
ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
while(rs.next()){
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for(int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++){
        row.add(rs.getString(i));
    }
    oblist.add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First: Do not load all records. Why would you even do that? You could implement some kind of pagination in your application. 
I.e. Add two simple buttons below your table "Previous" and "Next" and "Search" field above. In beginning, load i.e. 100 records. Upon each click, load next 100 records etc. If user is looking for specific record, he could use "Search" field.

Second: Load your records in background thread to keep your application UI always responsive and prevent freezing. Read more about [concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

Comment: This does run in a background thread. Other programs allow to load as much data as needed, and to compete I would like to allow the same thing. HeidiSQL loads the same query of data and puts it into a table in about 5 seconds.

Comment: Then how your application freezes if you are doing it "properly"?

Comment: could it be `tableView.setItems(rows.get(0));` that is killing it? that runs on the FX Thread...

Comment: @RyanNaddy That piece of code should actually run on FX thread. You only run your task on background thread and publish "chunks" of data to FX thread. JavaFX components should be updated on FX thread.

Comment: That code doesn't Do anything to modify the Application it just builds data and saves it to an ArrayList, so I am running it in the background. Once that completes, I run the code that updates the JavaFX Application. It is what makes the table and places it in the Application.

Comment: So what is taking the time: the code you posted, or the call to `tableView.setItems(...)`?

Comment: @James_D according to my debugging, it never gets to `tableView.setItems(....)`, so my best guess would be that it is the code I posted.

Comment: @RyanNaddy Once again, I appeal not to load all records. I can't tell what could be wrong from those pieces of code you provided. If you show which part runs on background and which part runs on FX thread, that could explain freezing.

Comment: The second piece of code is where the issue is, and it runs in the background. In netbeans I did debugging, and it never gets to the code after the while loop. Maybe if I let it run for an hour it will, but after about 3 minutes it should have gotten there and it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
        if(stmt.getUpdateCount() > -1){
            stmt.getMoreResults();
            continue;
        }
        if(stmt.getResultSet() == null){
            break;
        }
```

with

```
        if(stmt.getUpdateCount() > -1){
            if (!stmt.getMoreResults()) {
                break ;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That has no effect on the speed of converting the result set to an observable table (The part that seems to be the bottleneck).

Comment: Can you confirm that you ever exit your main while loop? You said earlier it never gets to the stage where you call tableView.getItems()...

Comment: Yeah, for smaller queries it works fine. I have done queries that return 100k rows and it exits the loop